# How do I link to Licensed Qt Libraries statically with CMake using find_package?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, linker

I'm porting a Visual Studio 2010 project to CMake and Visual Studio 2015.
I have it building and linking with default behavior w/regards to Qt

```
find_package (Qt5 5.9.3 COMPONENTS
    Core
    Multimedia
    Network
    Widgets
    Xml
    XmlPatterns
    REQUIRED)
```

What I want to do is take advantage of the fact that I have a developer license and should have the ability to static link to the Qt libraries without building from source, significantly cleaning up my application directory.

I am setting up the linkage with

```
target_link_libraries (${ProjectName}
    Qt5::Core
    Qt5::Multimedia
    Qt5::Network
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::Xml
    Qt5::XmlPatterns)
```

what else do I need to make it link statically?

Comment: If you have a developer license, you can easily ask Qt directly. They give some support to people with developer licenses

Comment: I'll do that too. I'll leave this up, see if I get an answer here first.
Google-fu has been irritatingly bad at getting me specific results to my CMake questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this is not already done, you will have to build Qt statically.

In a nutshell, you have to install perl, python, optionally jom and follow the instruction at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-building.html

After downloading the source, starting the shell, the configure command would look like the following

```
configure.bat -platform win32-msvc -release ^
-nomake examples ^
-nomake tests ^
-static
```

#### SSL

You will have to also decide if you want [SSL support or not](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ssl.html#enabling-and-disabling-ssl-support). If no, simply give the option:

```
-no-ssl
```

If yes, an additional option similar to

```
-openssl -I %OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR% -L %OPENSSL_LIBRARY_DIR%
```

would have to be pass.

OpenSSL version [used in the Qt5 provisioning script](https://github.com/qt/qt5/blob/5.11/coin/provisioning/common/windows/openssl.ps1) could be used.

```
$version = "1_0_2o"
$externalUrl = "https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL-$version.exe"
```

### Graphics Driver, WebEngine, ...

You will also have to make some decision in that regards: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-requirements.html

Comment: After conferring with Qt directly I can confirm that even their licensed developer distributions do not contain statically linkable libraries.